# Exception clicking on sort/show by details [showopendialog] [JFileChooser]

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, show, jfilechooser

This is just an example:

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Asgfsa {



    private JFileChooser fc;

    public Asgfsa(){
        fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Asgfsa b = new Asgfsa();

    }

}
```

Happens:

> Exception occurred during event dispatching:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
>       at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:333)
>       at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:288)
>       at sun.swing.FilePane.fixNameColumnWidth(FilePane.java:1143)
>       at sun.swing.FilePane.access$2300(FilePane.java:46)
>       at sun.swing.FilePane$6.componentResized(FilePane.java:1076)
>       at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Component.java:5971)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5925)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2034)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4512)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2092)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4342)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:610)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:280)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:195)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:189)
>       at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:1058)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:220)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:608)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:280)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:195)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:180)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:172)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:133)

Comment: Must be a problem in my work computers. Because in college and at home everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add a FileFilter (use the setFileFilter() method) to the dialog before opening it.

Comment: I have tried the method: setFileFilter and addChoosableFileFilter. 
Do not fix anything, thanks.